# How to handle multiple choices on Apache Superset?

Tags: sql-server, apache-superset

I'm trying to use Apache Superset do display some inquiries and I can't figure out how to display and add filter do dashboard when there are multiple choice answers.

In a simple example, let's say I have these questions:

- PersonId
- Date
- Gender (one choice)

  - M or F
- Diet (multiple choice)

  - Mediterranean
  - Vegan
  - Paleo
  - Gluten-Free
  - Other
- Drinks (multiple choice)

  - Beer
  - Wine
  - Soda
  - Coffee
  - Tea
  - Others

Example data :

| PersonId | Date | Gender | Diet | Drinks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2024-01-20 | M | Mediterranean, Paleo | Beer, Wine, Coffee |
| 2 | 2024-01-19 | F | Vegan, Other, Gluten-Free | Others, Soda |
| 3 | 2024-01-18 | M | Mediterranean, Gluten-Free | Beer, Tea |
| 4 | 2024-01-17 | F | Vegan, Paleo | Wine, Others, Coffee |
| 5 | 2024-01-16 | M | Other, Gluten-Free | Soda, Coffee |
| 6 | 2024-01-15 | F | Mediterranean, Vegan, Paleo | Wine, Tea |

Everything else works if there's just one option, but when there's multiple choices, how could I do things like create a pie chart for the diet options? Add a filter on the dashboard for diet? It just shows the comma delimited strings. I'd like to add the charts to a dashboard and be able to filter a person that drinks tea and soda and diet is vegan, for example.

I'm using an mssql connection, tried to do some custom sql/calculated columns to split the results but no luck. Don't know if there's something obvious that I'm not seeing?
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.